# Making Curved List in html without canvas

Tags: jquery, html, css, plugins

I want to make curved list as shown below using jquery and css.

[image]

How to do it.

I tried with transform but didn't work. How to achieve or any jquery library available for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `css3` `border-radius` property to draw curves. If you want complex curves just create a few elements and add them together.

I found this jsfiddle on the internet. It hope it serves your needs. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yijiang/nDxYJ/)

If you want something more specific you may have to specify your question.

Best regards

Comment: how to add data on curved  border as shown in above img

Comment: create html elements and set them relative to the curve (curve: position:relative, text: position:absolute). you then are able to set the offset (top, left, bot, right) to adjust the popsition.

Comment: i need to have a scrollable list...it would be difficult to change top left everytime if someone scroll

Comment: everytime? the positioning of the text is relative to the curve so you set it only once. The parent element must be of position: relative, the child has to be position: absolute. The offset will then be calculated relatively to the parent.

Comment: when the curve moves, positioning of  li or div need to change even though its position absolute

Comment: How does the curve move??? I dont understand what your final goal is. Can you update your question? Please make some drawing or a clear statement.

Comment: curve will not move...but when i scroll the curve...'b' should take place of a and c should take place of b and soon....how to achieve this

Comment: You can use waypoints.js to find out when you trigger the onScroll event after you scrolled by X px. You then bind a function to the onScroll event which will content-replace a with b, b with c etc. (only the text node) see jquery .text() or .innerHTML() or .value()

Answer (score -1):

Your other option can be 
[Curved element with other elements as positioned in an absolute way](http://jsfiddle.net/alanmehio/psLq3cue/)

```
<div id="curves" class="width">
    <div id="curve1"></div>
    </div>
   <div id="one">a</div>




 #curves div {
    margin-top: 100px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 5px solid #999;
}


#curves.width div {
    border-color: red red  transparent transparent;
    /* top right bottom left */
}



#curve1 {
    border-radius:  100% 100% 100% 0;
}


#one {
    position: absolute;
    left: 300px;
    top: 105px;
}
```

If you don't want to hard code the absolute position as in the Fiddle, you will be to find the  absolute element position  by doing some math equation using java-script/jquery

Hope this could help